# Inherit from recursively defined class

Tags: c++, inheritance, recursion

I have a quad tree defined like this:

```
class QuadTree{
public:
    QuadTree(): is_leaf(false), NW(NULL), NE(NULL), SW(NULL), SE(NULL) {};

    // Pointers to children (northwest etc.)
    QuadTree* NW;
    QuadTree* SW;
    QuadTree* SE;
    QuadTree* NE;

    bool is_leaf;
    int value;
};
```

I would like to inherit from that class, e.g.

```
class SpecialQuadTree: public QuadTree{
public:
    int foo;
};
```

However, this doesn't work like expected:

```
void insertValueIntoTree(int value, SpecialQuadTree* tree){
    if(is_leaf){
        tree->value = value;
        return;
    }

    if(/*north-west is the right tree to insert into*/){
        tree->foo = 42;
        insertValueIntoTree(value, tree->NW); // error
    }else if(...){
        /*possibly insert into other children*/;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains that it cannot convert from `QuadTree*` to `SpecialQuadTree*`.
Of course the pointers to the children are still pointers to base class objects.

How can I inherit from the base class *and* have its pointers be pointers to the derived class?

EDIT: I've edited the code to reflect my intentions better: I have to use a member of the 
derived class, so changing the signature is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use template to achieve this

```
template<class Subtype>
class QuadTree{
public:
    QuadTree(): is_leaf(false), NW(NULL), NE(NULL), SW(NULL), SE(NULL) {};

    // Pointers to children (northwest etc.)
    Subtype* NW;
    Subtype* SW;
    Subtype* SE;
    Subtype* NE;

    bool is_leaf;
    int value;
};
```

and define your SpecialQuadTree as:

```
class SpecialQuadTree: public QuadTree<SpecialQuadTree>{};
```

then the type conversion can be avoid

Answer (score 2):

> Of course the pointers to the children are still pointers to base
>   class objects.

Yes *but pointers of the base are not pointers of children class objects*. You can not implicitly convert from `QuadTree*` to `SpecialQuadTree*`. What if there is one more `OneMoreSpecialQuadTree` class derived from `QuadTree` and you are storing this object in pointer `NW`. You need to change the signature of `insertValueIntoTree` to accept `QuadTree*`.